# How to scroll the Admin side list pannel in prestashop 1.6.3

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have  more than  12 fields  to be displayed in the list view of the list pannel as  shown below in my admin cms  , but my problem is that  it breaks and I want to add the scroling for the pannel, where to edit or which page or css need to be changed to cater for this horizontal scrolling .or How to do this .

[image]

Comment: Ask yourself if you need that many fields.

Answer (score 1):

add in `.bootstrap .table` in [admin folder]/themes/default/css/admin-theme.css:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

or add in the files [admin folder]/themes/default/css/admin-theme.css:

```
table.order{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: #table-product  i did  not find this  tag

Comment: how  to override this  css admin-theme.css to do this ?? Is it possible to override  the css?For me  "overflow-x: scroll;" works  for #content.bootstrap .panel not for .bootstrap .table